# How to display name in the from address?

Tags: php, email

I have a site in PHP.In this when I send the invitation to people it takes the from address as mysitename@servername.Instead of this I want o display the Mysitename
.How can I do.I have the code shown below.

```
                    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'To:'. $value . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From:Mysitename'."\r\n";
```

How can I show like in users email's from address is Mysitename?

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$headers .= 'From: Mysitename <mysitename.com>' . "\r\n";
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something along the lines of:

```
$headers .= 'From: Mysitename <owner@mysitename.com>' . "\r\n";
```

You need 'From' to be proper email address.